# Question about calculus of variation.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations

What is the difference between finding maxima or mimima i.e. critical point of a function and calculus of variation?

Comment: It's the same basic ideas, it's just a lot more complicated to actually prove all of the relevant conditions for extremization.  There's more subtlety with things like weak vs strong variations which doesn't exist in optimization in scalar calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean. The difference is one is the  maxima and one the minima. Perhaps you mean in the method? Then there is no difference initially. It is similar to finding the local maxima and minima for a differentiable function of one variable. You find the extreme points in the first pass, then you need other methods to determine what those extreme points are (local max or min).